# How to count the unique values of a column and append each value to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

The tutorial suggests this solution

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
content_ratings = {}
for row in apps_data[1:]:
    c_rating = row[10] #the content rating that says which app is suitable for which age
    if c_rating in content_ratings:
        content_ratings[c_rating] += 1
    else:
        content_ratings[c_rating] = 1
print(content_ratings)
```

The output is

```
{'17+': 622, '4+': 4433, '9+': 987, '12+': 1155}
```

I just want to understand the code logic. The line says `if c_rating in content_ratings:` is supposed to return `False` as it doesn't meet the condition since the `content_rating` itself is empty so `c_rating` is not in the dictionary. How does this logic find the content rating and append it to the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines in if-else statement looks same, but there is slight difference, `+` sign:

```
if c_rating in content_ratings:
    content_ratings[c_rating] += 1
else:
    content_ratings[c_rating] = 1
```

`content_ratings[c_rating] = 1` this is how an element is added into dictionary in python. Also you can update existed element dictionary in same way; here `content_ratings[c_rating] += 1` you get the existing element and increase its value.

So, you are right, when `if c_rating in content_ratings:` returns `false`, it adds elements, otherwise, it updates its value (increasing count).

You can see basic operation on dictionary in [docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)